# Hypothesis testing with confidence interval

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

[image]

In this question, I have no idea why there shows the value 375, how can I use it? And also for part(iii) I cannot get the idea what the question is asking. Could anyone helps me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the context of this question in the book or course, there are several
ways to interpret this question. I will pick the one that seems most likely
to me.

You are given information for finding the sample variances $S_x^2 = 285/9$
and $S_y^2 = 375/14.$

In (i) you are asked to test $H_0: \mu_x \ge \mu_y$ against $H_a: \mu_x < \mu_y$
at the 5% level. This is a one-sided, two-sample test. For normal data,
two such tests are in common use: the 'pooled' test (in which it is assumed
that $\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2$ and the 'Welch' or 'separate variances'
test (in which the assumption of equal population variances is not made).

I suppose (i) intends you to assume equal variances and do
the pooled test. It would use the following 'pooled' estimate of
the 'common' (shared) population variance $\sigma^2 = \sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2,$ 
$$S_p^2 =\frac{(n_x - 1)S_x^2 + (n_y - 1)S_y^2}{n_x + n_y -2}
= \frac{285 + 375}{23},$$
to compute the $T$-statistic, having Student's t distribution with $n_x + n_y - 2$ degrees of freedom (under $H_0$). I refer you to your text for details.
[By contrast, the Welch test does not use $S_p^2$ and has a formula
for determining the degrees of freedom for the test statistic.]

In part (ii), I suppose you are asked to test whether the equal variance
assumption is realistic. That is, to test $H_0: \sigma_x^2/\sigma_y^2 = 1$
against the alternative $H_a: \sigma_x^2/\sigma_y^2 \ne 1,$ at the 1% level.
This test uses the variance-ratio statistic $F = S_x^2 / S_y^2,$ which
has Snedecor's F-distribution with numerator degrees of freedom 9 and
denominator degrees of freedom 14 (under $H_0$). Again, I refer you to
your text for details.

*Note:* Based on theory and many simulation studies, I believe that
current statistical practice is to use the Welch separate-variances test,
unless there is solid prior knowledge or experience that the two population
variances must be equal.

The suggestion to do a preliminary F-test to determine whether
to do a pooled or Welch test has been deprecated. One of several difficulties
lies in trying to assign an overall level of significance to the 'hybrid' two-test procedure. Another difficulty is that the F-test has poor power
unless sample sizes are quite large, and using a pooled
test with unequal population variances can lead to misleading P-values,
especially when sample sizes are unequal.

However, it is a reasonable exercise, in a beginning statistics course, to practice these three two-sample
tests, pooled and Welch t, and F. I believe this exercise is asking you to
practice the pooled and F tests.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer of part i and ii, but could you please explain for part iii as well? I have no idea how to calculate the probability.

Comment: I have no idea what probability of 'well known' distribution the author has in mind. If you run a pooled t test when variances are unequal, sample sizes are unequal, and the larger variance is associated with the smaller sample, then the actual significance level of the test may be much larger than planned. That difficulty may be what the author has in mind. But I know too little about the background for this problem to know what approach is desired. Under $H_0$ the P-value should have a UNIF(0,1) dist'n. But not if eq var assumption violated. Have you discussed that?